# order of function call inside cout

Tags: c++, c++14, cout

I am trying to know the order of execution of functions inside the cout statement

I tried this set of codes

```
#include < iostream >
using namespace std;
int i=0;
int sum(int a)
{
    i++;
    return a+i;
}
int main()
{
    cout << sum(3) << sum(2) ;
    return 0;
}
```

"I expected the output to be 44, but the actual output is 53"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

> Order of evaluation of any part of any expression, including order of
>   evaluation of function arguments is unspecified (with some exceptions
>   listed below). The compiler can evaluate operands and other
>   subexpressions in any order, and may choose another order when the
>   same expression is evaluated again.
>
> There is no concept of left-to-right or right-to-left evaluation in
>   C++. This is not to be confused with left-to-right and right-to-left
>   associativity of operators: the expression a() + b() + c() is parsed
>   as (a() + b()) + c() due to left-to-right associativity of operator+,
>   but the function call to c may be evaluated first, last, or between
>   a() or b() at run time

In your line

```
cout << sum(3) << sum(2)
```

the order of the two `operator<<` calls depends on the operator you use (here `<<` so left-to-right), but the evaluation of each subexpression, namely `sum(3)` and `sum(2)` has no defined order and depends on the mood (most optimized compile approach usually) of your compiler.

For info here is a list of operators associativity: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: but if its execution is random it should have printed at least one time 44 but it didn't although i have compiled 20 times at least

Comment: @ankursuman: It's not "random"; it's *arbitrary*. That is, there is no specification as to what the order for a particular compiler will be, but there will be some order.